# Object is stopped but its position still changing

Tags: game-engine, objects

I'm applying a linear velocity to an object. Sometimes it collides with other objects and bounces some distance. I need to detect when my character stop.
What I did was assign to a property the character's X + Y positions and, with a property sensor, detect if changes that property.
The problem is that the object is apparently stopped, but the property still changing, specifically, because the X position is continuosly changing.

Comment: I believe the property sensor only accesses the game properties you add in the logic editor, not standard object properties. The physics sim will use inertia to keep moving an object, try adding some friction to the floor to counteract the inertia. I am thinking a python script to detect movement.

Comment: The property I added is from the logic editor. Also, my object has some friction.